# WP REST API: check if user is logged in

Tags: rest-api, authentication, nonce

The idea is to show or hide some sections of the site in a theme that's fetching all data from the REST API, using AngularJS.

I thought this check would help me (nonce is passed as header, as suggested by docs):

```
wp_localize_script('angularjs', 'params', array(
    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('wp_rest'),
    'nonce_verify' => wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST['X-WP-Nonce'], 'wp_rest')
));
```

The `nonce` parameter works and i can pass it as request header through AngularJS, successfully logging. But the `nonce_verify` didn't as expected.

So the question: is there a way to check if an user is logged in when using cookie authentication? Thank you.

EDIT:
I localized nonce's value cause i needed to get it in this piece of angularJS code. That's where auth happens:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function () {
            return {
                'request' : function (config) {
                    config.headers = config.headers || {};

                    config.headers['X-WP-Nonce'] = params.nonce;

                    return config;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Are you trying to get an HTTP header with this `$_REQUEST['X-WP-Nonce']` ?

Comment: @ClemC Sorry, my bad. I used $_SERVER

Comment: Why don't you simply use `is_user_logged_in()`?

Comment: @JackJohansson Using `is_user_logged_in` works, but i wondered if i could rely on the rest api in full.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't pass your nonce to your JavaScript to verify it, since client side scripts can be easily manipulated. Instead, you should get the nonce from your front-end content, and then pass it to server to verify it.

After verification, you should decide to output content by *server*, not by your *JavaScript* file.

Something like this:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    if ( wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST['X-WP-Nonce'], 'wp_rest') {
        // Nonce is correct!
    } else {
        // Don't send the data, it's a trap!
    }
}
```

As a side note, REST API offers its own method to fetch the passed queries. So, you can get it this way in your callback function:

```
function foobar( \WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    $nonce = $request['X-WP-Nonce'];
}
```

Comment: That's what i thought to do, i'm not exposing my nonce's value

Comment: You are localizing the script and passing both nonce and verification to the script, which can be accessed by using `params.nonce`!

Comment: Now i got your point...

Comment: I can simply write a custom script in the browser's scratch pad and extract that data. Once it's passed to the browser, it's over.

Comment: I updated the post explaining where i'm passing headers and authenticating to REST Api. Sadly it uses the params.nonce which i exposed before.

Comment: About `params.nonce_verify`: if true it would show some content for logged users only. In case it was exploited, hacker would get the html structure, but empty

Comment: That's a good answer except the fact that he shouldn't be able to access his HTTP header this way... Would you mind taking this into consideration in your answer? I can delete mine then.

Comment: @ClemC I've already mentioned that in a side note.

Comment: I mean that you can't get a HTTP header named `'X-WP-Nonce'` with `$_REQUEST['X-WP-Nonce']`... Instead `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_WP_NONCE']` may return it.

Comment: I'm accepting this one although it should be edited taking the case of nonces through HTTP headers into account.
But now i have another issue...